# What is this long brownish bug (found in Maine home in early August)?

Tags: bug-identification

I found this bug months ago (August, in southern Maine): I found it crawling on my wall, (second floor), only time I've ever seen one of these particular bugs in my house.

**Edit:** I managed to get a rough measurement based on another photo I had, and it seems to have been about 0.7 inches long (from top of head to bottom end of body) and 0.2 inches wide at widest part ("shoulders")

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing a longhorn borer of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it - almost certainly the [Poplar-borer beetle](https://www.insectidentification.org/insect-description.asp?identification=Poplar-Borer-Beetle) (*Saperda calcarata*). Distinguishing characteristics are the golden/yellow spots under the black speckles. Borers all have that shape to the head and thorax. Longhorn indicates the long antennae.

These are quite a destructive pest of poplar and a few other species in much of North America.

Note I'm not an entomologist of any sort, or even from North America - just good at googling things.

Comment: Oh No!!  Sob!!! Chestnut, hemlock, ash, boxwood, now poplar?

Comment: @ab2 - not just poplar, this one will go for a bunch of different trees, including aspens and cottonwoods.